# VAR model for a short time series yields autocorrelated residuals

Tags: model-selection, autocorrelation, residuals, small-sample, vector-autoregression

I am currently conducting an analysis on a small sample ($n=41$) first-difference VAR. The underlying data is only available in yearly terms so there is unfortunately no possibility to increase sample size. All variables are unit roots and stationary in first difference. Predicting a first difference VAR with 6 variables, the maximum lag length that provides a stable VAR is $p=3$. The model's predictive power of $p=3$ is better than the previous models; however, I am highly concerned about the remaining auto-correlation in the residuals series.

[image]

My econometrics textbook and several articles recommend that I am supposed to add lag length; but increasing the lag order to $p=4$ yields an unstable model.

I have one variable which is adjusted for a strong structural break by regression on a dummy variable and predicted residuals used as estimated values. Accounting for the structural break clearly causes the autocorrelation in the residuals series, but not accounting for it would bias the model results.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What will you use your model for? Are you interested in hypothesis testing, forecasting, or yet something else? Because if you care about hypothesis testing, autocorrelated residuals will affect estimated standard errors. But if you want to do forecasting, this is not really a problem. A model with a high lag order will have high estimation variance, which can be a serious concern with such short time series. Then you might wish to allow for some autocorrelation just to cap the estimation variance.

Comment: @ Richard: Thanks for the comment and the correction! The model is used for hypothesis testing and the response of shocks to the different equations (IRFs).

Comment: Maybe for clarification: I have estimated my model for both cases, one accounting for the structural break in only one series and the other neglecting the structural break. The problem of autocorrelation only occurs, when the residuals series is used as predicted variable.

Comment: Funny... A *neglected* structural break should normally cause autocorrelation in residuals, but you have it the other way around. But why account for the structural break outside the model when you could actually include a dummy variable inside the model for that? Maybe you would get better results (I don't know)?.. $p=3$ with $6$ variables means you are estimating $18$ coefficients + an intercept per each equation. On $41$ data point that is really a lot. I would consider smaller models.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Richard! I will try the proposed changes to the model!

Comment: Any progress so far? It would be interesting to see the variables themselves, the estimated model and its diagnostics (e.g. residual autocorrelations). If you have them handy, of course.